# Multiple INSERTS in one query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm having trouble with my sql query. I will like to INSERT some data in first table and then copy ID from last insertion to another table in same query.

I'm pasting code bellow and hopping someone will show me the right way, cuz I'm getting some ";" error.

```
sqL = "INSERT INTO Narocilo(ID_stranke, datum_sprejema, rok_izdobave, status_narocila, dodal) " + " VALUES('" & txt_idstranke.Text & "','" & Format(datum_sprejem.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & Format(datum_izdobava.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & txtstatus.Text & "','" & cmb_zaposleni.Text & "'); INSERT into ZadnjiID(zvisaj) SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM Narocilo"
```

Comment: This is not one query - it's two in one string. Break it down into two parts and execute them separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access (JET/ACE) will not allow multiple SQL statements in the one query. You're getting the error because you're putting a second statement after the semicolon.
You need to break down what you're doing. `@@IDENTITY` will still work, providing you don't kill the connection first. For example:

```
 Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstr)
 Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
 conn.Open()
 command.Connection = conn

 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Narocilo(ID_stranke, datum_sprejema, rok_izdobave, status_narocila, dodal) " + " VALUES('" & txt_idstranke.Text & "','" & Format(datum_sprejem.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & Format(datum_izdobava.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & txtstatus.Text & "','" & cmb_zaposleni.Text & "');"

command.ExecuteNonQuery()
command.CommandText = "SELECT @@Identity"
Dim idd As Integer = command.ExecuteScalar
command.CommandText = "Your second INSERT statement using idd as the id here"
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

`@@IDENTITY` will only work with Integer typed AutoNumbers in access - not GUIDs.
As a side note, you should really be parameterising your queries to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
 sqL = "INSERT INTO Narocilo(ID_stranke, datum_sprejema, rok_izdobave, status_narocila, dodal) " + " VALUES('" & txt_idstranke.Text & "','" & Format(datum_sprejem.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & Format(datum_izdobava.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & txtstatus.Text & "','" & cmb_zaposleni.Text & "'); INSERT into ZadnjiID(zvisaj); SELECT @@IDENTITY"
```

This will returns Primary key Autoincrement columns value for current connection.

If this table has Identity column than it will return it value back.

But for that use SqlCommand.ExecuteScaler so that it will return object value and you can use it to another table.

Thank you.

Comment: Dunno if I'm doing something that program does not like but after using your statement I'm still getting error _Characters found after end of SQL statement._

Comment: Please explain meaning of this query "INSERT into ZadnjiID(zvisaj);"

Comment: I've put that out because I will try it the way you showed me. To get last ID from query and put it into another table. But I'm still getting error with query bellow:
`sqL = "INSERT INTO Narocilo(ID_stranke, datum_sprejema, rok_izdobave, status_narocila, dodal) " + " VALUES('" & txt_idstranke.Text & "','" & Format(datum_sprejem.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & Format(datum_izdobava.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & txtstatus.Text & "','" & cmb_zaposleni.Text & "'); SELECT @@IDENTITY" `

Comment: try to use this query sqL = "INSERT INTO Narocilo(ID_stranke, datum_sprejema, rok_izdobave, status_narocila, dodal) " & " VALUES('" & txt_idstranke.Text & "','" & Format(datum_sprejem.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & Format(datum_izdobava.Value, "d. MM. yyyy") & "','" & txtstatus.Text & "','" & cmb_zaposleni.Text & "'); SELECT @@IDENTITY"